# Visual studio C# Excel object library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a program that runs perfectly on my PC, I'm using a Windows 8 with 2013 Office. My program is using Excel. Now the program has to function on a Win7/Office2010 combination. Can I just import/include the Object library?

The Object library is now shown in the references, can I get them manually? Like download + install it and there it is?

Comment: No;  The library was updated to support Office 2013.  This program would have to be updated to reference that new version of the library instead

Comment: @Ramhound I don't really understand, I don't want to _update_ the library, I need the programm to be working with Excel 2010, it works with Excel 2013

Comment: I apologize I didn't understand it was already working with Office 2013.  The answer is the same the library you are using will have to be changed to the version that is supported by Office 2010.

Comment: I know, but the question is, where do I get the library?

Comment: Its located [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2451) despite it saying Office 2010 Beta.

Comment: @Ramhound, I installed [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508) but it only shows the Office 14 PIA, not the Excel 14 PIA.

Comment: I know, it doesn't work like that..
I made a VM with win7/Office2010 and included the reference.